# How can I average a geometrical series' values with a single formula (in Excel)?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following mathematical problem. I have a series of 15 steps. The initial value of the series is 36900. This value decreases by 0.6% on every step of the series. Which formula I can use to calculate the average value of the steps within the series, without having to calculate the values of all the steps of the series?

I have tried calculating the last value of this series and doing the average of both, the first and the last value. However, this does not work as it is not a linear series.

Thanks in advance,

Paco

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: How would you compute the values of the first steps?

Comment: @Gribouillis 36900*(1-0,6%)^1

Comment: The [sum of a geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) can be computed with a pretty cute formula. Do that, then divide by the number of terms.

Comment: This is not crystal clear, what is $(1-0,6\%)$ ?

Comment: @prets thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first term has starting value 36900, and decreases by 0.6% after every step, this is a geometric series, since there is a common ratio between each term, and the sum of these terms will look like this:

> $$S_{n} =\sum_{n=0}^{14} 36900\cdot (0.994)^n$$

To calculate this, use the formula for geometric series $S_n = a_1\frac{(r^n -1)}{(r-1)}$.

> $$S_{15} = 36900\cdot\frac{(0.994^{14}-1)}{(0.994-1)} \approx496928.2541$$

Since you have 15 steps in the series, divide this by 15 and you should have the answer you are looking for which is $\approx33128.55027$

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Isn't 0.6%=0.006?

Comment: @Adithya is right. And the fraction must be (1-0,994^14)/(1-0,994), but thanks. Your answer helped me enough to solve my problem.

Comment: My bad, I was in a rush to answer because I was at school! I will edit my answer in case anyone else needs help with a similar problem.